# Dockerfile for a gitlab container

Tags: docker, debian, docker-compose, dockerfile, gitlab-omnibus

I am doing a school project where I must install gitlab ce in a debian Docker container.
I came up with something but the gitlab installer gets stuck on :
ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run

I read somewhere you can Ctrl+C and reconfigure to skip this error but as it is a school project I can't afford doing anything messy.

Would you have any tips for me ?

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM xterm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y dialog apt-utils curl openssh-server ca-certificates postfix
RUN curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | bash
RUN EXTERNAL_URL="http://0.0.0.0:3000" apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated gitlab-ce

RUN gitlab-ctl reconfigure

EXPOSE 443 80 22

CMD ["gitlab-ctl","start"]
```

Thanks your your time :)

**EDIT**

I added this line before gitlab-ctl reconfigure but still stuck !

```
RUN cp /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/files/default/gitlab-runsvdir.conf /etc/init/
RUN systemctl restart gitlab-runsvdir
```

**EDIT 2**
I installed sudo and added it at each command. No improvment.

Comment: See here an example of implementation: https://developer.ibm.com/code/2017/07/13/step-step-guide-running-gitlab-ce-docker/. I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to use the Gitlab CE docker image for this project, but it may help.

Comment: I learnt a few things but I am still struggling with this stuck ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run

Comment: I've made a little search and I've found this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/common_installation_problems/README.md#reconfigure-freezes-at-ruby_blocksupervise_redis_sleep-action-run. You have all the steps for resolving your problem. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something but it does not solve anything ><

Comment: OK I run debian /bin/sh through docker to monitor the install step by step.
The action run freeze is during the "apt-get install gitlab-ce".
So the lines I add afterwards does not have any effect obviously.
I need to do something before.

Comment: Try to give sudo rights for apt-get install. So before running apt-get install, run sudo apt-get install

Comment: Well now the "ruby block action run" freezes on gitlab-ctl reconfigure.
Same problem ><

Comment: Try to get sudo rights to ruby as well.

Comment: you mean -> sudo curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash. I am not familiar with ruby

Comment: No, I think that you can just execute "sudo ruby" and ruby must be a environment variable.

Comment: Have you resolve this issue? I also got this problem when trying to build a docker image with Gitlab. The solution mentioned in official website has no effect :(

Comment: Hi, I did not find any working solution I simply lost some points on my school project :/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to build your own gitlab docker images from Dockerfile, you can use the official docker images by gitlab instead. More details about it on Gitlab Docker images.

A quick way is run:

```
# docker pull gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
# sudo docker run --detach \
--hostname gitlab.example.com \
--publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 \
--publish 22:22 \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

The image is based on Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: I wish I could use this official image. But I can't for this particular school project.